# Get part of the result into columns instead of lines

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a query about internal and external trainings. Every training has 1 or more speakers. What I want is to have a column for every speaker.

I was checking on aggregate functions, but I couldn't find the one solving my problem.

```sql
select  e.sid
       , e.access_kz EXTERN1
       , z.zuname VERTRETERPERSONAL1
  from MDEV e
    join MDEVCAL ec on (ec.klient_id = e.klient_id and ec.EV_sid = e.sid) 
    left outer join MDEVCALS ecs on (ecs.klient_id = e.klient_id and ecs.ev_sid = e.sid and ecs.evcal_sid = ec.sid) 
    left outer join MDZHD z on (z.klient_id = e.klient_id and z.sid = ecs.MDZHD_SID)
```

I use left outer joins because a training doesn't have to have a speaker but can have X different speakers

What I want to have is something like this:

```
SID | Extern1 | VERTRETERPERSONAL1 | VERTRETERPERSONAL2 | VERTRETERPERSONAL3 ...
```

Comment: So do you want the number of columns to represent each trainer against the training? Dynamic number of columns?

Comment: Yes, that should be the result.

Comment: The single query will not provide you such a result as a number of columns must be known to SQL engine before it executes the query. If you are willing to use PL/SQL then we can help.

Comment: my problem is that I can't use PL SQL in this case. (It is a query for a report and doenst support PL SQL). It's possible if give a static amount of trainers to the query?   For example if I say that i only want first two trainers?

Comment: Yes, It is possible with static trainers

Comment: What you are looking for is pivot query: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the Following query will resolve your problem but with the static list of trainers.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            E.SID,
            E.ACCESS_KZ   EXTERN1,
            Z.ZUNAME      VERTRETERPERSONAL
        FROM
            MDEV E
            JOIN MDEVCAL EC ON ( EC.KLIENT_ID = E.KLIENT_ID
                                 AND EC.EV_SID = E.SID )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN MDEVCALS ECS ON ( ECS.KLIENT_ID = E.KLIENT_ID
                                              AND ECS.EV_SID = E.SID
                                              AND ECS.EVCAL_SID = EC.SID )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN MDZHD Z ON ( Z.KLIENT_ID = E.KLIENT_ID
                                         AND Z.SID = ECS.MDZHD_SID )
    ) PIVOT (
        MAX ( VERTRETERPERSONAL )
        FOR VERTRETERPERSONAL
        IN ( '<VERTRETERPERSONAL_NAME1>' AS VERTRETERPERSONAL1, '<VERTRETERPERSONAL_NAME2>' AS VERTRETERPERSONAL2, .... )
    );
```

Cheers!!